# How to execute Ansible playbooks with LDAP authentication to hosts?

Tags: authentication, ansible, ldap, pam

I am trying to configure a setup where my playbooks are executed by getting credential for the host from an external authentication source (LDAP/PAM).

I have a regular `/etc/ansible/hosts` inventory file, with IP and username of hosts. During execution of the playbook, it should dynamically acquire the password from an external LDAP/PAM server for each host's respective user.

Is this doable?

Comment: I don't know much about it but maybe this https://github.com/devgateway/ansible-ldap-auth     will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, it is not doable ( not very much sure about this ) but what you can do is store the credentials in some file and then us it as extra-vars while running playbook.

otherwise you can use expect module to pass the password as extra variable.